# Connection between Jar Jar Binks and the film "Alice"?

Tags: character, analysis, star-wars, george-lucas, alice

I was watching Jan Švankmajer's 1988 film *Alice* recently and was struck by the strong apparent similarity between the Frog Footman character that takes delivery of an invitation for Alice and Jar Jar Binks. Specifically, the animation of the frog's tongue as it reaches out to catch insects resembles Jar Jar's. Has George Lucas ever mentioned this film as an influence? Is there any evidence that the resemblance is anything more than coincidence?

Comment: Could you provide images and/or videos to highlight the similarities you're asking about?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**I don't believe there is a connection.**

George Lucas has spoken about his inspiration for Jar Jar Binks, at the [D23 Expo in California](http://www.cinemablend.com/new/Jar-Jar-Binks-Was-Inspired-By-Classic-Disney-Character-77507.html):

> I can't even begin to tell you how much of an influence Disney has had
>   on me... I will say one secret that nobody knows; not many people
>   realize that Goofy was the inspiration for Jar Jar Binks… I know that
>   you will look at him differently now. It's pretty obvious, actually,
>   but, um, I love Goofy and I love Jar Jar.

It's certainly possible that *Alice* had *some* sort of influence, but in lieu of Lucas confirming this, and looking at the fact Jar Jar Binks character is certainly not unique in cinema, I think we have to assume **it was not an influence**.